# Error en NodeJS MySQL. El cliente rest se queda congelado al enviar la solicitud

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Estoy haciendo una api de notas. Al hacer la inserción desde mi endpoint me da el error de que título no puede ser null a pesar de que se los paso como parámetro.
Este es el código que tengo. Es lo único que me falla, el resto funciona bien.

```
const insertNote = (req, res) => {
  const { titulo, descripcion } = req.params
  const sql = "INSERT INTO notas (id, titulo, descripcion, completado) VALUES('', ?, 0)"
  
  connection.query(sql, {titulo, descripcion}, (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err
  })
}
```

Como se puede ver tengo la consulta sql y los parámetros que le asigno. Pero al hacer el post desde mi cliente rest me sale el siguiente error:
[image: Error de consulta en mysql]

He probado a cambiar la estructura de la consulta. Pero aun así me sigue fallando.

**Edito**

He pasado por console log las vafriables y me salen como undefined. A petición así es como manejo la ruta

```
router.put("/api/upload/", controller.insertNote)
```

También he probado a cambiar el método por post y nada.
Así es como envío las peticiones desde el cliente junto coon el mensaje de error que me muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edito 2**

He probado a instalar bodyParser siguiendo un tutorial y ahora las variables si reciben los datos. Pero el cliente se queda en bucle procesando la petición y no la envía nunca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el estado actual de la función problemática

```
const insertNote = (req, res) => {
  const titulo = req.body.titulo
  const descripcion = req.body.descripcion

  const sql = "INSERT INTO notas (id, titulo, descripcion, completado) VALUES('', ?, 0)"

  console.log(titulo)
  console.log(descripcion)

  connection.query(sql, {titulo, descripcion}, (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err
  })
}
```

**Edito 3**

Esto es lo que aparece en la tabla de MySQL cuando ahora envío la petición

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los tres últimos registros debería aparecer los datos que envío. Pero no es así

**Edito 4**

He cambiado el objeto que recibían los parámetros por un array y ahora el cliente se queda congelado en un bucle infinito al enviar la petición. Pero los datos se guardan correctamente

Comment: Has depurado las variables para ver que no sean efectivamente `null`?

Comment: Me salen como undefined. Pero es lo que no entiendo. He puesto el body con los datos en el thunder client

Comment: Estás usando el *parser* en Express? `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }) )` y además `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Acabo de probarlo pero sigue fallando igualmente. Dice que título no puede ser nulo

Comment: Y como estás enviando la petición? `req.params` se consume de una forma específica. Puedes mostrar como manejas la ruta en Express y cómo envías la consulta desde el cliente?

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta con nueva información.

Comment: Solo he leído tres líneas de tu código, pero estás seguro de que esto está bien?? `const sql = "INSERT INTO notas (id, titulo, descripcion, completado) VALUES('', ?, 0)"` le pases 4 valores a `notas` pero luego solo tres en `values`...

Comment: Al principio le pasé un cuarto valor. Pero cuando enviaba la petición me daba error. Al quitar el segundo interrogante ese error desaparecía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea obtener 2 valores enviados en una petición `http` a una API desarrollada con [Express](https://expressjs.com). Los valores eerán usados para actualizar una tabla de MySQL mediante la iserción de un nuevo registro.

Entre los problemas que se observan en el código debo destacar que estás tratando de usar [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params), pero la ruta que estás tratando de consumir no tiene ningún parámetro configurado:

```js
/api/upload/
```

En tu pregunta dices también que has intentado pasar los valores en el cuerpo de la solicitud y has instalado y configurado una librería llamada [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). Sin embargo, si utilizas ExpressJS v.4.16 o superior, no es necesario instalar dicha librería ya que la misma viene por defecto como parte de `express`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que deseas usar efectivamente parámetros en la URL que consumes, debes entonces crear el enrutamiento adecuado en la misma.

Por ejemplo:

```js
router.put("/api/upload/:titulo/:descripcion", ...);
```

De esta manera le estoy indicando a Express que maneje la ruta de tal forma que el valor de título y de descripción son parte de la ruta, es decir son parámetros.

Como puedes imaginar, esto no es lo más adecuado para lo que intentas hacer, ya que por defecto los valores pasados por la URL serán codificados. Por ejemplo, si una descripción es muy larga: "Hola, esta es una nota de prueba", el resultado de la URL a consumir se verá así:

```js
/api/upload/prueba/Hola%2C%20esta%20es%20una%20nota%20de%20prueba
```

Siendo el título: "Prueba" y la descripción: "Hola%2C%20esta%20es%20una%20nota%20de%20prueba"

Como se observa, tal vez no sea la mejor forma de enviar este tipo de datos al servidor.

**Usando el `body` o cuerpo de la solicitud**

Lo mejor en estos casos es enviar la información en el cuerpo de la solicitud. Para ello podrías enviar los datos serializados en formato JSON.

Para poder leer los datos del cuerpo de la solicitud, Express necesita analizar dicho cuerpo. Aquí es donde entra en juego el *parser* o analizador del cuerpo. Express dispone de 2 métodos para lograr el objetivo:

- [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json): es un middleware que analiza las solicutudes entrantes en busca de un Payload JSON.
- [`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) : es una función middleware que analiza las solicitudes entrantes y busca Pyloads codificados mediante urlencoding.

Sin entrar en muchos detalles de cómo funcionan ambos métodos, simplemente hago la sugerencia de que uses ambos como parte esencial de tu aplicación, recordando que debes usarlos antes de la declaración de cualquier ruta en la que sea necesario su uso. Por ejemplo, para tenerlo disponible en cualquier ruta en toda tu aplicación, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//...
app.use(routes ...);
```

Una vez que hemos usado el middleware para analizar el cuerpo de la solictud de forma correcta, podemos entonces pasar a la segunda parte del problema.

**Actualizar sí y sólo si podemos hacerlo**

Uno de los problemas con tu código es que da las cosas por sentadas. Es decir, falla simplemente porque en ningún momento te das a ala tarea de verificar si puedes insertar o no un nuevo registro.

Una de las reglas de oro en el desarrollo backend es: "NUNCA CONFÍES EN LO QUE ENVÍA EL CLIENTE".

Tu método para actualizar la tabla podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
const insertNote = (req, res) => {
  const { titulo, descripcion } = req.body;
  if(!(titulo && descripcion)) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Datos insuficientes, falta titulo y/o descripcion",
      status: 400
    });
  const preparedSQL = "INSERT INTO notas SET ?";
  const values = { titulo, descripcion };
  connection.query(preparedSQL, values, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error('Uuuups');
      console.error(error.message);
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Error al crear nota",
        values,
        status: 500
      });
      console.log(result);
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: "Nota creada"
        result,
        status: 201
      });
    }
  })
}
```

En el código anterior se puede apreciar que en todo momento se envía una respuesta al cliente con `return res.status()...`. De esta forma el cliente sabrá que la petición ha sido procesada por el servidor y la misma recibe una respuesta.

Lo primero que se hace es obtener los valores de título y descripción desde el cuerpo de la solicitud:

```js
const { titulo, descripcion } = req.body;
```

Luego verificamos que los valores de título no sean cadenas vacías, `null` ni `undefined`. Si alguno de ellos o ambos es de este tipo, devolvemos un mensaje al cliente para indicarle que la solicitud no ha sido procesada porque hay un error en la misma. Es por ello que el estado de la respuesta se establece a 400 (Bad Request).

```js
if(!(titulo && descripcion)) {
  return res.status(400).json({ ... });
}
```

Por último, creamos la sentencia preparada para la inserción de los datos a la base de datos.

No sé cómo tienes configurada tu tabla, pero por lo general el valor de `id` es auto numérico y auto generado por el motor de la base de datos. También el valor del campo `completado` podría ser insertado automáticamente en una inserción mediante un valor por defecto. Pero en general sólo debes controlar que los valores pasados en el objeto que recibe el método `query` son los justos y necesarios para poder llevar a cabo la operación sobre la base de datos.

En cuanto a la forma de enviar los datos desde el cliente al servidor, esto va a depender mucho del tipo de cliente que estés usando. En tu pregunta se muestra una imagen de lo que supongo que es POSTMAN. Por lo cual, enviar los datos en el cuerpo de la solicitud de la forma en que lo hace Postman es más que sucifiente.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya funciona. Ahora entiendo que debo enviar siempre una respuesta. El cliente enviaba la petición pero se quedaba esperando una respuesta que nunca llegaba